# Visual studio setup passes where to download?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, visual-studio

I want to install visual studio but when I run the setup tt doesn't ask me where to download it just says wait until your process is done before asking what contents to download and where to download them.

Is it normal?

I ask this because I had a earlier version of vs setup that worked fine that I didn't download.

But this time it is different?

Windows 7
64-bit

visual-studio setup for win7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using VS 2017 it is normal for you to configure the installation before the download(s) begin. Have a look at this video tutorial. You may find a guided installation of VS 2017 helpful.

https://youtu.be/T4E_nU2F-iY?t=224

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @nvm, could you please provide the specific version of VS that you are trying to install?

Comment: @Mokubai, I have to disagree with your assessment. The question was "is it normal", and the answer I've given was "using VS 2017 it is normal".  If all I provided was a link to a video I would have agreed with you. Maybe the op will clarify the version in question, and ask for more specifics. That way we can provide more detailed answers.

Comment: Hence why I didn't vote to delete. You answered the question of "is it normal" but you don't state it completely clearly. Saying "have a look at this video tutorial" seems either a bit redundant or is not actually directly answering whether or not it is normal. The other answer is clearer in directly answering the question.

Comment: I see. Let's hope op comes back with a specific version of VS so I can be completely clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for the current VS installers to manage the download itself without asking you where to save the files to.

The current VS installers require minimal interaction. For many this is not an issue as it makes the installation process relatively quick (apart from the large download), for others, they might not appreciate that this means the installer is making assumptions about how they wish to install it.